# Fabric register user Error: self signed certificate

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am running the fabric ca server using the docker container and using the fabric node for enrolling and register the users. when, I enroll the admin through fabric node its works fine, its create the wallet folder. When i am trying to register the user its throw the error saying

```
 Failed to register user : Error: Calling register endpoint failed with
 error [Error: self signed certificate]
```

Please any suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The register command should look like:

```
fabric-ca-client register -d --id.name $ORG_ADMIN --id.secret $ORG_ADMIN_PASSWORD --id.type client --id.affiliation $ORG_AFFILIATION
```

The fabric-ca-client-config.yaml inside your FABRIC_CA_CLIENT_HOME should look like:

```
url: https://ca.org0.domain.tld:7054

mspdir: msp

tls:
  certfiles: ca-tls.pem

csr:
  names:
    - C: US
      ST: New York
      L: New York
      O: Org0
      OU: Department0

caname: org0-ca

bccsp:
    default: SW
    sw:
        hash: SHA2
        security: 256
        filekeystore:
            keystore: msp/keystore
```

Please check url and tls.certfiles (if your CA is using TLS).

The msp directory must contain the CA administrator's credentials after enrolling it in the previous step.